# How to organize controllers in a directory?

Tags: controller, laravel

I just started using Laravel. When I use codeigniter or zend framework, I can organize my controller into a separate directory. For example, I can create 'user/permission.php' and 'user/group.php'.

How do I do that with Laravel?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Convert `/` into `_`. So your `controllers/user/permission.php` controller would be

```
class User_Permission_Controller
```

### UPDATE:

You also have to route to the controller changing `_` to `.`
So route similar to

```
Route::get('/', 'user.permission@index');
```

You can see more details on it here. http://codehappy.daylerees.com/using-controllers

Comment: I missed something, updating answer.

Answer (score 2):

(This is basically the same answer as Robbo gave with some extra examples).

I use the following (tested) structure.
I have a file controllers/admin.php which looks like:

```
class Admin_Controller extends Base_Controller {
    ...
}
```

And I have files like controller/admin/groups.php which look like:

```
class Admin_Groups_Controller extends Admin_Controller {
    ...
}
```

And in the routes.php file I have

```
// Route to all controllers
Route::controller(Controller::detect());
```